# How Do I use recursion for Division in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

I am trying to Define a recursive procedure called (nDivide x y n) with three parameters x, y, and n. It returns the result of x divided by y n times. I have a function that divides
(define (Divide x y)
(/ x y)).
Now I am trying to use the Divide functions in to nDivide and I cant get it to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursive implementation (though why would anyone do this):

```
(define (nDivide x y n)
  (if (= n 0)
      x
      (Divide (nDivide x y (- n 1)) y)))
```

Here is an iterative implementation of nDivide, which is more straightforward:

```
(define (nDivide x y n) 
  (if (= n 0)
      x
     (nDivide (Divide x y) y (- n 1))))

(define (Divide x y) (/ x y))
```

Example:

```
(nDivide 10000 3 4)
;Value: 10000/81
```

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to do something `n` times:

- Do it once, then do it `n - 1` times;
- Do it `n - 1` times, then do it once.

You get different procedures depending on which path you choose:

```
; divide, then recurse
(define (nDivide x y n)
    (if (zero? n)
            x
        (nDivide (Divide x y) y (- n 1))))

; recurse, then divide
(define (nDivide x y n)
    (if (zero? n)
            x
        (Divide (nDivide x y (- n 1)) y)))
```